# NoClassDefFoundError with external jars

Tags: android, jar, external, noclassdeffounderror

I need to add some external jars to my Android project. So I googled what the best way was to do that. And I did exactly what needs to be done :

1. I created a new folder in my project called libs (from inside eclipse)
2. I right clicked on libs and clicked on import. General -> FileSystem and then I browsed to the external jar files.
3. I right clicked on my project, went to Configure Build Path and added the jars (NOT external jar) in the Libraries tab.
4. In the Order and Export tab, I checked the jars I had just added.
   After doing this, both my jars show up under 'Referenced Libraries'.

But I still get the NoClassDefFoundError. Please help me. I need to know how to fix this. Thanks.

Here's the Logcat :

```
04-09 00:14:54.799: D/AndroidRuntime(1673): Shutting down VM
04-09 00:14:54.799: W/dalvikvm(1673): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a661f8)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax.activation.DataHandler
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at com.example.easyMail3.GmailSender.sendMail(GmailSender.java:53)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at com.example.easyMail3.EasyMail3Activity.onCreate(EasyMail3Activity.java:18)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-09 00:14:54.803: E/AndroidRuntime(1673):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Not to dishearten you, we had a similar problem for only one of our team members (imported jars worked fine for everyone else, build paths identical) that we never managed to resolve for them. Out of curiosity, are you using a real phone & if so what is it?

Comment: @T.Kiley I'm using the Nexus S

Comment: @T.Kiley It is the same with the emulator.

Comment: Fair, different from ours then. For everyone else we I think we just added it as a Jar & that was all there was to it, good luck!

Answer (score -1):

In Eclipse , if it is  a webproject, basic place to keep your jars is under lib folder in WEB-INF.
if it is a JavaProject make sure you find your libraries in BuildPath(libraries)

and if you are sure about them being placed correct, then you really didn't get correct jar file.